# Cosa vuol dire "per questo" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Ho un dubbio a proposito d'un passaggio di Luigi Pirandello in "Il fu Mattia Pascal", nel capitolo 9.

Mattia Pascal vuole contrarre un'amicizia con qualcuno, c'è una persona possibile:

> Già nella trattoria che frequentavo in quei giorni, un signore, mio vicino di tavola, s’era mostrato inchinevole a far amicizia con me. Poteva avere da quarant’anni: calvo sì e no, bruno, con occhiali d’oro, che non gli si reggevano bene sul naso, forse per il peso de la catenella pur d’oro. **Ah, per questo un ometto tanto carino!** Figurarsi che, quando si levava da sedere e si poneva il cappello in capo, pareva subito un altro: un ragazzino pareva. Il difetto era nelle gambe, così piccole, che non gli arrivavano neanche a terra, se stava seduto: egli non si alzava propriamente da sedere, ma scendeva piuttosto dalla sedia.

Non credo di capire bene l'espressione «per questo». Pascal prima dice che il suo conoscente è stato «un ometto» (cioè un piccolo uomo), poi spiega tutto a proposito delle sue piccole gambe ecc. «Per questo» non vuol dunque dire «per la ragione del suo cadere degl'occhiali, del suo aspetto, della sua mancanza di destrezza…» (un uomo carino, cioè amabile… nel suo modo), perché la ragione è ben altra. Ma è appunto questo il solo significato che posso attribuire all'espressione: «per una ragione». Dunque c'è uno sbaglio d'interpretazione, ma quale? Vorrei capire bene la frase in grassetto. Forse «per questo» vuol dire «per giunta»?

Mille grazie!

Comment: Come intercalare, secondo me assume un significato tipo "Proprio un ometto tanto carino" o "Per l'appunto, un ometto tanto carino" o "Precisamente, un ometto tanto carino). (interpretazione personale)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi grazie, mi pare di sentirla l'intonazione. :)

Comment: Per il mio modo di sentire, direi che "per questo" si riferisce agli occhiali e catenella d'oro, malfermi: una cosa elegante e che fa anche un po' tenerezza. Credo poi che "perciò" non sia esattamente equivalente a "per questo", credo che "perciò" abbia più forza e introduca una conclusione che si ritiene (o si vuole far ritenere) ovvia. E poi, "perciò" è molto diverso da "ah, sapete che...".

Comment: @linuxfan grazie!

Comment: Ripeto, mia opinione personale, ma credo che sia più una specie di intercalare piuttosto che l'introduzione di una spiegazione. Non dissimile da "Ah, guarda, proprio un ometto tanto carino!"

Comment: Mah, la spiegazione linguistica può essere discussa perché la teoria linguistica (una piccola digressione) non è ancora bene sviluppata, ma mi è importante di "avere sentito" questa frase, di sapere cosa vuol dire in generale, come "si pronuncia", con quale mente, a che fa pensare ecc, e credo di vedere che voi tutti e due siano infatti d'accordo, in qualche senso… Almeno mi pare…

Comment: Concordo – e anche nel mio caso è una semplice opinione a orecchio – con @RiccardoDeContardi che sia appunto un'espressione per confermare o sottolineare quello che si sta dicendo, un po' come “a volerla dire tutta” o simili.

Comment: Visto che la descrizione che precede l'espressione non è proprio delle più lusinghiere, io non riesco a non leggerla in chiave contrastiva ("nonostante questo") o almeno come relativizzazione ("a parte questo").